# Async method throws exception instantly but is swallowed when async keyword is removed

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm getting some behaviour which I cannot understand when throwing exceptions in async methods.

The following code will throw an exception immediately when calling the ThrowNow method. If I comment that line out and throw the exception directly then the exception is swallowed and not raised in the Unobserved event handler.

```
public static async void ThrowNow(Exception ex){
    throw ex;
}

public static async Task TestExAsync()
{
    ThrowNow(new System.Exception("Testing")); // Throws exception immediately
    //throw new System.Exception("Testing");   // Exception is swallowed, not raised in unobserved event

    await Task.Delay(1000);
}

void Main()
{  
    var task = TestExAsync();
}
```

Something a little more confusing, if I remove the `async` keyword from the `ThrowNow` method, the exception is swallowed yet again.

I thought async methods run synchronously until reaching a blocking method. In this case, it seems that removing the async keyword is making it behave asynchronously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I thought async methods run synchronously until reaching a blocking method.

They do, but they're still aware that they're executing within an asynchronous method.

If you throw an exception directly from an async *void* method, the async mechanism is aware that you'd have no way of observing that exception - it won't be thrown back to the caller, because exceptions thrown in async methods are only propagated through tasks. (The returned task becomes faulted.) It would be odd for an exception thrown *before* the first blocking `await` expression to be thrown directly, but exceptions afterwards to be handled differently.

As far as I'm aware, an exception thrown by an async `void` method is passed directly to the synchronization context, if there is one. (A continuation is posted to the synchronization context that just throws the exception.) In a simple console app, there *isn't* a synchronization context, so instead it's thrown as an unreported exception.

If you change your `void` method to return `Task`, then instead you'll just have an exception which *could* have been observed, but isn't (because you're not using the return value in `TestExAsync`).

Does that make any sense? Let me know if you'd like more clarification - it's all a bit tortuous (and I don't know how well documented it is).

EDIT: I've found a *bit* of documentation, in the C# 5 spec section 10.15.2:

> If the return type of the async function is void, evaluation differs from the above in the following way: Because no task is returned, the function instead communicates completion and exceptions to the current thread's **synchronization context**. The exact definition of synchronization context is implementation-dependent, but is a representation of "where" the current thread is running. The synchronization context is notified when evaluation of a void-returning async function commences, completes successfully, or causes an uncaught exception to be thrown.

Comment: Yup, the general recommendation for `async` is to never return `void` unless you need to do so to match a method signature (for overloading a subclass or implementing an interface).

Comment: As far as I know, using `async`-`await` from a console application isn't documented very well.

Comment: "If you throw an exception directly from an async void method, the async mechanism is aware that you'd have no way of observing that exception - it won't be thrown back to the caller," - In this case though, the async void method is throwing an exception back, instantly, or so it appears. (I should mention the use of LINQPad here so I guess it's a console app under the hood). Could it be that the exception being thrown in the async void method is doing so in such a quick fashion that it appears to be throwing instantly? BTW this is not an unobserved exception.

Comment: @VincePanuccio: No, the problem isn't the speed. The method isn't directly throwing the exception - it's telling its synchronization context about the exception, which is in turn rethrowing it because it hasn't got any other way of indicating it.

Answer (score 0):

> Something a little more confusing, if I remove the async keyword from the ThrowNow method, the exception is swallowed yet again.

Exceptions are not "swallowed".

In addition to what Jon Skeet said, consider this code where `ThrowNow` is not marked `async`:

```
static void ThrowNow(Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}

static async Task TestExAsync()
{
    ThrowNow(new System.Exception("Testing"));

    await Task.Delay(1000);
}

static void Main()
{
    var task = TestExAsync();

    Console.WriteLine(task.Exception);
}
```

As you can see, exceptions are not "swallowed", they're just communicated to you in the task returned from an asynchronous method.

Obviously, that also means you cannot `try` `catch` them, unless you await the task:

```
static void Main()
{
    AsyncMain();
}

static async void AsyncMain()
{
    var task = TestExAsync();

    try
    {
        await task;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exceptions can be swallowed http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/10217876.aspx

Comment: @VincePanuccio They can be unobserved and posted to the synchronization context, as Jon Skeet said. But you claimed they are "swallowed" when `ThrowNow` is not marked `async`. My answer shows you that nothing is swallowed _in that scenario_, which seems to be what your question is about.